# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Employee, int

Tags: java

I'm just trying to do a simple `if` statement which tells you what personal allowance you get, depending on the age that you are. There is a field for "age" in the `Employee` class, which is why I have passed over the age. But I'm getting the error: 
    The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Employee, int.

Where am I going wrong? Here is my code:

```
double calculatePersonalAllowance(Employee age){

    if (this.age < 65) {
      personalAllowance = 94440;

    }

      else if (this.age >= 65 && <75){
      personalAllowance = 10500;

    }

      else if (this.age >75){
      personalAllowance = 10660;

    return personalAllowance;
  }
```

Comment: `age` is a bad name for an employee variable.

Comment: And it's bad to have method parameters that aren't used in the method.

Comment: Not posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) always makes our life more difficult (pay specific attention to the "self-contained" part).

Comment: er, why did you choose double for the type of `personalAllowance`? Note that if you're trying to represent a fractional amount (like .1), floating point numbers have some inherent design choices that give inexact results.  Monetary values should be represented in something like `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 6):

`else if (this.age >= 65 && <75)`

Should be:

```
else if (this.age >= 65 && this.age <75)
```

It's highly recommended to read [15.23. Conditional-And Operator &&](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.23) and [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html).

Also, it's redundant to have a parameter that's never used.. If you don't use `age`, remove it from the method's signature:

```
double calculatePersonalAllowance()
```

Don't worry, the `age` you're referring to is the *class member* and not the local one.

Comment: I'm still getting the error that the operator ">=" is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what's going. I've changed it to how you said.

Comment: Edit your question and post the changes there.

Answer (score 1):

First:

> "There is a field for "age" in the Employee class, which is why I have passed over the age"

You have not passed over the age, you have done the following: (Employee age) which passes over a reference to the Employee object, not the age field.  the 'age' variable between the brackets is a variable local to the method referencing the Employee object which called the method,  in order to get the age you will need to either get it directly from the employee object you are referencing, or via a getter method.

Second:
The way an If expression is read is as follows:

```
if(expression){do code}  //where expression returns either true or false
```

Or with some operators:

```
if(expression && expression)
```

You have as follows:

```
else if (this.age >= 65 && <75){ 
//Which equates to the below:
else if(expression && <75){
```

The compiler is expecting an expression but finding an operand. You have age as the argument passed to your method, but also appear to be trying to access a field named age.  I would recommend changing the method argument to something like (Employee emp).  Then change wherever you have this.age to emp.age.

```
else if (emp.age >= 65 && emp.age <75){
//You effectively make
else if(expression && expression){
```

which satisfies the compiler!

Answer (score 1):

I think `this.age` need to be change as `employee.age` and `(this.age >= 65 && <75)` need to change as `if (employee.age >= 65 && employee.age<75)`

the complete method as below.

```
 double calculatePersonalAllowance(Employee employee){
        double personalAllowance = 0;
    if (employee.age < 65) {
        personalAllowance = 94440;

    }else if (employee.age >= 65 && employee.age<75){
          personalAllowance = 10500;

    }else if (employee.age >75){
          personalAllowance = 10660;           
  }
      return personalAllowance;
 }
```

Comment: er, why did you choose `double` for the type?  Note that if you're trying to represent a fractional amount (like .1), floating point numbers have some inherent design choices that give inexact results.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse.. thanks.. i am not added anything new. i just modified what is present in OP's question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the return signature in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If in you method you want to check propery age of it's parameter you must use parameters all the way.In that case method can be static like this:

```
static double calculatePersonalAllowance(Employee employee)
{
    double personalAllowance = 0.0;//default value
    int age = employee.age;
    if (age < 65) 
    {
      personalAllowance = 94440;
    }
    else if (age >= 65 && age <75)
        {
            personalAllowance = 10500;
        }
        else if (age >75)
        {
                personalAllowance = 10660;
        }
    return personalAllowance;
}
```